Apache Ignite - Load balancer nodes standalone
I installed 4 apache ignite nodes on 4 virtual machines that are in a vmware cluster, one question I have is how do I connect to the cluster? Do I connect via the IP of any node? Or do I need to put nginx "in front" to do the load balancing? I didn't find anything about this in the official documentation.

A standard load balancer wouldn't really work since it wouldn't know the distribution of the data.
A thin client can either connect to one or all of the nodes. There are some performance advantages when connecting to all nodes since it can connect directly to the node that stores the data rather than operating via a proxy.

Perfect, I understand, but what if the node that the applications are connecting to goes down, what would it look like? Thinking that my applications will connect to the IP of one of the nodes, if it drops the connection will be interrupted, that's what I'm confused about.
